# Top-k on a list of dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there an easy way to perform the max k number of key:values pair in this example

```
s1 = {'val' : 0}
s2 = {'val': 10}
s3 = {'val': 5}
s4 = {'val' : 4}
s5 = {'val' : 6}
s6 = {'val' : 7}
s7 = {'val' : 3}
shapelets = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7]
```

I want to get the max 5 numbers in the shapelets list, knowing that it contains a key of name "val" and to which a value is assigned.
The solution here resides in parsing through the list of dict elements and get the max n numbers of it ( in this case the max 5 values )

What can be a simple solution, does operator library in python supports such operation ?

Comment: By max 5 values do you mean the 5 largest values?

Comment: @Farhan.K yes I do, I want to get the maximum values in this list dict thing

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
s1 = {'val': 0}
s2 = {'val': 10}
s3 = {'val': 5}
s4 = {'val': 4}
s5 = {'val': 6}
s6 = {'val': 7}
s7 = {'val': 3}
shapelets = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]

print(sorted(shapelets, key=lambda x: x['val'])[-5:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in linear time using [numpy.argpartition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(list(map(itemgetter("val"), shapelets)))

print(arr[np.argpartition(arr, -5)][-5:])
```

The 5 max values will not necessarily be in order, if you want that then you would need to sort the k elements returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

s1 = {'val': 0}
s2 = {'val': 10}
s3 = {'val': 5}
s4 = {'val': 4}
s5 = {'val': 6}
s6 = {'val': 7}
s7 = {'val': 3}
shapelets = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]

heapq.nlargest(5,[dct['val'] for dct in shapelets])
# [10, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

`heapq` is likely to be faster than `sorted` for large `lists` if you only want a few of the largest values. Some discussions of `heapq` vs. `sorted` are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666602/python-heapq-vs-sorted-complexity-and-performance).

Comment: Pretty sure nlargest is  `O(n log k)` so it should be faster than calling sorted.