# Sorting a nested list by a certain element without the sorting function.

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

If I have a nested list like this:

```
L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]
```

How can I sort it from highest to lowest based on the last number in each of the sub lists without using the sorting or sorted function?

Output:

```
final = [['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]
```

The only way I know how to do it is with the sorting function, but I would like to know how to do it without that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `sorted` or `sort`?

Comment: I just want to know different ways of sorting lists.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to write your own sorting function, which is only useful as an exercise.

Comment: Then consult your favourite Algorithms textbook or check out Wikipedia for algorithms like QuickSort, MergeSort, InsertionSort, etc.

Comment: `Python` sorting is fast enough, why to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]

keys = [(int(v[-1]),k) for k,v in enumerate(L)]
final = []

for i in range(len(keys)):
    #find the next biggest element according to last element of the list.
    final.append(L[max(keys)[-1]])
    keys[max(keys)[-1]] = ''

final
Out[83]: [['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]
```

Comment: That is essentially SelectionSort (except that SelectionSort can be implemented in-place). It is of O(n^2) complexity even in best case. Much better algorithms exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) that can be implemented.  Python's `sorted` builtin was [thoughtfully implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) long ago by Tim Peters.

However, here is another sorting option using `heapq`:

```
import heapq
import operator as op

heapq.nlargest(len(L), L, key=op.itemgetter(-1))
# [['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]
```

By comparison, notice the similarity to `sorted`, which has several intuitive options:

```
import operator as op

expected = [['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]

r1 = sorted(L, key=op.itemgetter(-1))[::-1]
r2 = sorted(L, key=op.itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
r3 = list(reversed(sorted(L, key=op.itemgetter(-1))))

assert r1 == r2 == r3 == expected
```

`sorted` is generally fast with some exceptions where `heapq` is faster.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666602/python-heapq-vs-sorted-complexity-and-performance) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) function. You can pretty much switch some signs to reverse the output:

```
def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr

    pivot = arr[len(arr)/2]

    left = [x for x in arr if x > pivot]
    middle = [x for x in arr if x == pivot]
    right = [x for x in arr if x < pivot]

    return quicksort(left) + middle + quicksort(right)
```

The next step would be to make sure you're extracting the proper numbers, and make sure you can map those back to the parent list so you can drop those into the right place again — [Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907777/7968653) has a good approach:

```
L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]

keys = [(int(v[-1]),k) for k,v in enumerate(L)] # This line here
```

That line basically creates a list of tuples that store the numbers we wanna sort by, and the index of that number's parent list on the overarching list. So basically, for `L`, `keys = [(2, 0), (1, 1), (5, 2)]`.

So you'd alter the `quicksort` function to account for all this, by creating a subfunction that can be used recursively:

```
def quicksort(arr):
    # Put the actual sorting function into a subfunction that can be called recursively
    def subsort(arr2):
        if len(arr2) <= 1:
            return arr2
        pivot = arr2[len(arr2)/2]
        left = [x for x in arr2 if x > pivot]
        middle = [x for x in arr2 if x == pivot]
        right = [x for x in arr2 if x < pivot]
        return subsort(left) + middle + subsort(right)

    # Get the value-key pairs and sort them
    keys = [(int(v[-1]),k) for k,v in enumerate(L)]
    keys = subsort(keys)

    # Do the mapping back to the original array fed into the main function
    final = []
    for i in keys:
        final.append(arr[i[1]])

    return final
```

And with that:

```
>>> L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]
>>> quicksort(L)
[['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]
```

**Note:** If there are two items with the same number in the last position those are gonna get their original relative position (to one another) in the original list *reverted*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/7968653) for more details on tuple comparison, and note that we're sorting stuff in *descending* order here (otherwise, they'd just keep their original position relative to one another). So:

```
>>> L = [['Simon', '1', '2'], ['Henry', '1', '5'], ['Finn', '1', '2']
>>> quicksort(L)
[['Henry', '1', '5'], ['Finn', '1', '2'], ['Simon', '1', '2']]
```