# Extract the indices of the n highest values in a list

Tags: python, list

What is the most efficient way to extract to a list the indices corresponding to the n highest values of another list, while preserving the list we're extracting the indices from?

For example, let's say we have the following list of indices:

```
foo = [107,6,34,12,82]
```

If we requested the indices of the 2 highest values of the list foo, it should return us the following list:

```
bar = [0,4]
```

Here's what I'm running right now, it's really inefficient and not elegant at all and I don't really know how to improve it:

```
foo = [107, 6, 34, 12, 82]
tmp = list(foo)
bar = []
no_of_indices_wanted = int(input())
for n in range(no_of_indices_wanted):
    bar.append(foo.index(max(foo)))
    foo.pop(foo.index(max(foo)))
foo = tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to annotate indices on each item, and then use `heapq.nlargest` to obtain the highest two of the list, after which you extract the indices into a list:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(map(itemgetter(0), heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(foo), key=itemgetter(1)))))
```

This outputs: `[0, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
foo = [107,6,34,12,82]
n=2
[i for i, x in sorted(enumerate(foo), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:n]]
#[0, 4]
```

Comment: This would work if there aren't two of the same highest numbers in the list, which may or may not be a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort tuples of `(value, index)` and then recover the indices.

```
def n_highest(lst, n):
    ordered = sorted([(value, idx) for idx, value in enumerate(lst)], reverse=True)
    return [idx for value, idx in ordered[:n]]

print(n_highest([107, 6, 34, 12, 82], 2))
```

### Output

```
[0, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below approach too:

```
myList=[1,50,30,15,14]
sorted_ind_list=[]

for a in sorted((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList)):
   sorted_ind_list.append(a[1])

print(sorted_ind_list[0:2])
```

sort has Better performance over heap.

[comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666602/python-heapq-vs-sorted-complexity-and-performance)

Comment: This gives the highest two values, rather than the indices of the highest two values that the OP asks for.